# MapKit load locations from core data

Tags: swift, core-data, annotations, mapkit

I have trouble in loading information (locations) from core data, I have Core Data [Shops] with columns lat (latitude) and long (longitude). But cant load this to MapView.

```
   import UIKit
   import MapKit
   import CoreData

   class allMapPinsViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

var shop: [Shops]! = []

var appDelegate: AppDelegate!
var sharedContext: NSManagedObjectContext!

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    sharedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    mapView.delegate = self
    self.mapView.addAnnotations(fetchAllPins())
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func fetchAllPins() -> [Shops]? {
    do {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest (entityName: "Shops")
        let results = try sharedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [Shops]
        return results

 } catch let error as NSError {
    print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `addAnnotations(:)` method takes one argument, which is an array of `MKAnnotation`. You're passing it... nothing, because `allPins` has no return value. You need to change `allPins()` so that it returns an array of `MKAnnotation`.

To make `allPins()` do that, you'll need to construct an `MKAnnotation` for each lat/long pair, add that to an array, and return the array at the end of the function. `MKAnnotation` is a protocol, so you can't just instantiate it directly. You'll need to have some class that adopts `MKAnnotation`, create instances of that, and add those instances to the array.

Comment: I edited code with returning, but it shows error: Cannot convert value of type '[Shops]?' to expected argument type '[MKAnnotation]'

Comment: Does `Shops` adopt the `MKAnnotation` protocol?

Comment: You also need to handle the Swift optional correctly-- you're returning `[Shops]?`, which is optional, but you can't pass an optional to `addAnnotations(:)`. You should make sure you always return an array, not an optional array.

Comment: Thank you very match, I did it!

Comment: But what about title and subtitle, should I return it with array in MKAnnotation protocol as well?

Comment: Title and subtitle are part of `MKAnnotation`. You would include them on your objects that conform to the protocol.